# Custom Fields Not Showing

Tags: php

I have this custom field for a post:

```
key: price
value: 2000
```

I've added this to my loop:

```
<div class="buyitnow"><?php $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
if ( $price ) { ?>
Price: $<?php echo number_format($price ,",",",",","); ?>
<?php } else {} ?></div>
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
Price: $
```

Comment: where you trying echo this ?? function.php or page template ?

Comment: Was trying to echo this in index.php. I have an issue regarding this but it's a different question so I'd appreciate if you check it out.

Comment: you can't get `$post->ID` on index.php can you show full code of index.php

Comment: @Furquan Why can't you get `$post->ID` inside an index.php template?

Comment: Because this is `blog page` if you want to get id of page or post then you need to put this `var` inside the loop or `loop.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) wrong. The second parameter should be a number and you have a string-- a comma. What you want is something like

```
echo number_format($price,2,",",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, you need to *globalize* the `$post` global variable:

```
global $post;
$price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
```

If this is the problem, then you should be getting a PHP notice, because `$post` is undefined unless/until you globalize it. To see such a notice, you should set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php`.

### Edit

From this comment:

> Sorry, but I'm totally new to code, I learned what I wrote in the question above after hours of searching. Can you should me where exactly whould I add this? right after the `<?php`..?

PHP code must be placed within PHP code tags. For example:

```
<div class="buyitnow"><?php global $post; $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
if ( $price ) { ?>
Price: $<?php echo number_format($price ,",",",",","); ?>
<?php } else {} ?></div>
```

Change this:

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
```

...to this:

```
<?php global $post; $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering quickly! where should I add this? in which file and where? (and I heard that "Oh Boy!")

Comment: You need to globalize `$post` wherever you use it. In your case, you're using it as a parameter in your call to `get_post_meta()`, so you need to globalize it before that call.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm totally new to code, I learned what I wrote in the question above after hours of searching. Can you should me where exactly whould I add this? right after the <?php..?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Hey Chip, it still isn't working. Should I give the URL? I don't want to be banned for spamming.